# how can I download a file from a password protected folder in java

Tags: java, android, security, download, passwords

want to download a file from a online server and I don't want it to be acessible outside my application so I have protected the folder using the control panel , now I need to know how can I acccess and download that file in my java program ? Its an android app that downloads a database. My situation is that I have two databases, one for the free app and another for the paid version.And I dont want people downloading the paid version to the pc and using them on the free version app.Is there another easy way ?

Answer (score 0):

Please see the [Apache HttpClient Examples, Client authentication](http://hc.apache.org/httpcomponents-client-ga/examples.html). Android ships with these libraries by default.